# Select option without value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Line of code in question:

```
$(this).find('select option:first').val();
```

If my select has this structure:

```
<select>
    <option> -- choose -- </option>
    <option value="some_value"> Some text</option>
</select>
```

the jQuery code I posted above will return `--choose--` as a value. Is there a way I could understand if the option has a value or not, instead of returning the text in it?

Comment: If an option does not have a value, the text it contains is automatically used as the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).find('select option:first').attr('value');
```

NOTE: this will return `undefined` if the value attribute is not set

Answer (score 5):

In your case, if your first `option` have no `value` attribute, you can use this:

```
$(this).find('select option[value]:first').val()
```

This returns the first `option` tag from your `select` but requiring that it haves the `value` attribute.

**UPDATE:**

Based on @Samuel Caillerie's comment, you can use [multiple attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) to avoid IE bizarre behaviours:

`select option[value][value!=""]:first`

That worked on Chrome and IE 10 with compatibility mode set to IE 8.

Comment: Be careful : this does not work on IE8 or less (they add a value attribute for each option)...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie I do not know that. Thanks for the advice. I updated my answer.

Comment: Your edit seems interesting, but after some tests, it now gives "--choose--" in all browsers except IE7 where it gives the expected value of "some_value". But even in IE8, it don't work for me...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie strange IE behaviours, anyway, that was not the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$(this).find('select option:selected').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('select option:first').attr('value');
```